# How to create default value for reference argument for function in D?

Tags: function, reference, d

Signature of my function:

```
JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter)
```

The second argument must be passed by reference and to be optional. My nonworking variants:

```
JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter = 10);
JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter = int(10));
JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter = new int(10));
JSONValue get(string data); // override also does not work
```

DMD32 D Compiler v2.065

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the argument is `ref`, it must have an address. Therefore, it must be an lvalue expression.

You can do this:

```
JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter = *new int);
```

You currently can't use this syntax to also give the newly-allocated `int` a value. But, in D 2.066, you'll be able to write:

```
JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter = *new int(10));
```

This will allocate a new `int` on the heap, unless one is specified at the caller site.

You can also use a static variable, or a ref function call:

```
int defaultValue;

ref int defaultValueFun()
{
    auto i = new int;
    *i = 10;
    return *i;
}

JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter = defaultValue);
// or
JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter = defaultValueFun());
```

Be wary of this technique if `defaultValue` might be called while a reference to its `value` is still in use, though.

Comment: 1)  Error: no constructor for int

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. It's an upcoming feature, which will be available in the next D version.

Comment: `ref int parentCounter = *new int(10)` is a nice trick that I think we should document. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution at this point would be to just overload the function. e.g.

```
JSONValue get(string data)
{
    int dummy = 10;
    return get(data, dummy);
}

JSONValue get(string data, ref int parantCounter)
{
    ...
}
```

It also avoids any unnecessary heap allocations, unlike [cybershadow's suggestion of using `*new int(10)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22419749/160887) once 2.066 is out (though being able to do `*new int(10)` will definitely be cool).

Now, you seem to be indicating in your question that for some reason, overloading the function doesn't work:

```
JSONValue get(string data); // override also does not work
```

So, maybe this solution won't work for you, but without more information, I don't know why it wouldn't. Certainly, if you're dealing with free functions, it will, and if you're dealing with struct member functions, it will. The only possible problem that I can think of is if you're overriding a base class function, but even then, the only problem I can think of is if the base class declares

```
JSONValue get(string data, ref int parentCounter)
```

and you're trying to call the function via the base class rather than derived class, and if you're doing that, then having a default argument in the overridden function wouldn't help you any anyway, because the base class didn't declare one - the default argument would only work when used via the derived class. Certainly, you could override the base class' `get` and then add an overload in the derived class that looks like

```
JSONValue get(string data)
```

So, if declaring an overload like that isn't working for you, I'll need more details in order to help you figure out why it isn't working.